# Command pattern in javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, command

For an app I am developing I need to implement the Command pattern with support for undo/redo actions. I also want to use javascript ES6 new features like classes, constants etc.
I've never used this pattern thus **I am really interested in hearing what could be good implementations of this pattern using javascript es6 syntax**.

After reading about this pattern on Google I've written my own implementation using a small example with only 2 types of command (update and delete) and a mockup db for simplicity.

Please feel free to criticize/correct in any case!

mockupDB.js

```
// mockupDB.js


export default {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
}
```

Command.js

```
// Command.js

import mockupDB from "./mockupDB";


class Command {

    constructor(execute, undo, serialize, value) {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.undo = undo;
        this.serialize = serialize;
        this.value = value;
    }

}



export function UpdateCommand(key, value) {

    let oldValue;

    const execute = () => {
        if (mockupDB.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            oldValue = mockupDB[key];
            mockupDB[key] = value;
        }
    };

    const undo = () => {
        if (oldValue) {
            mockupDB[key] = oldValue;
        }
    };

    const serialize = () => {
        return JSON.stringify({type: "Command", action: "update", key: key, value: value});
    };

    return new Command(execute, undo, serialize, value);
}


export function DeleteCommand(key) {

    let oldValue;

    const execute = () => {
        if (mockupDB.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            oldValue = mockupDB[key];
            delete mockupDB[key];
        }
    };

    const undo = () => {
        mockupDB[key] = oldValue;
    };

    const serialize = () => {
        return JSON.stringify({type: "Command", action: "delete", key: key});
    };

    return new Command(execute, undo, serialize);
}
```

CommandManager.js

```
// CommandManager.js

export class CommandManager {

    constructor() {
        this.executeHistory = [];
        this.undoHistory = [];
    }

    execute(command) {
        this.executeHistory.push(command);
        command.execute();
        console.log(`Executed command ${command.serialize()}`);
    }

    undo() {
        let command = this.executeHistory.pop();
        if (command) {
            this.undoHistory.push(command);
            command.undo();
            console.log(`Undo command ${command.serialize()}`)
        }
    }

    redo() {
        let command = this.undoHistory.pop();
        if (command) {
            this.executeHistory.push(command);
            command.execute();
            console.log(`Redo command ${command.serialize()}`);
        }
    }
}
```

client.js

```
// client.js

import {CommandManager} from "./CommandManager";
import {UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand} from "./Command";
import mockupDB from "./mockupDB";

"use strict";

const main = () => {

    const commandManager = new CommandManager();

    console.log("DB status", mockupDB, "\n");
    commandManager.execute(new UpdateCommand("key2", "newValue2"));
    commandManager.execute(new DeleteCommand("key3"));
    console.log("DB status", mockupDB, "\n");
    commandManager.undo();
    commandManager.undo();
    console.log("DB status", mockupDB, "\n");
    commandManager.redo();
    commandManager.redo();
    console.log("DB status", mockupDB, "\n");

};

main();
```

output

```
DB status { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

Executed command {"type":"Command","action":"update","key":"key2","value":"newValue2"}
Executed command {"type":"Command","action":"delete","key":"key3"}
DB status { key1: 'value1', key2: 'newValue2' }

Undo command {"type":"Command","action":"delete","key":"key3"}
Undo command {"type":"Command","action":"update","key":"key2","value":"newValue2"}
DB status { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }

Redo command {"type":"Command","action":"update","key":"key2","value":"newValue2"}
Redo command {"type":"Command","action":"delete","key":"key3"}
DB status { key1: 'value1', key2: 'newValue2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an opinion-based question. In my opinion:

- OOP increases the amount of code, which is cumbersome for JS, so I would not use `class` for each role(invoker, command, receiver) of the command design pattern. A JS function with a closure to represent the command object is enough.
- There is one role missing in your implementation - the **receiver**. The client role should pass the receiver object satisfying the interface to the command object instead of using the concrete receiver object in the command object directly. This is called the dependency inversion principle. Command object and receiver object should depend on abstractions(receiver interface - the `interface` in TypeScript) and not on concretions(receiver concrete - the instance of a class)

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) of command pattern, we know:

> A command object knows about receiver and invokes a method of the receiver. Values for parameters of the receiver method are stored in the command.

> The receiver object owns the method that is called by the command's execute method.

- The last suggestion is variable naming. It may be better to change them to `redoStack` and `undoStack`.

My implementation will be:

```
const updateCommand = (receiver, data) => {
  let oldValue;
  const execute = () => {
    oldValue = receiver.get(data.key);
    receiver.update(data.key, data.value);
  }
  const undo = () => {
    receiver.update(data.key, oldValue);
  }
  const toJSON = () => {
    return { type: "Command", action: "update", data }
  }
  return { execute, undo, toJSON }
}


const deleteCommand = (receiver, data) => {
  let oldValue;
  const execute = () => {
    oldValue = receiver.get(data.key);
    receiver.delete(data.key)
  }
  const undo = () => {
    receiver.create(data.key, oldValue);
  }
  const toJSON = () => {
    return { type: "Command", action: "delete", data }
  }
  return { execute, undo, toJSON }
}


const commandManager = {
  redoStack: [],
  undoStack: [],
  execute(command) {
    this.redoStack.push(command);
    command.execute();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(command));
  },
  undo() {
    const command = this.redoStack.pop();
    if (command) {
      this.undoStack.push(command);
      command.undo();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(command));
    }
  },
  redo() {
    const command = this.undoStack.pop();
    if (command) {
      this.redoStack.push(command);
      command.execute();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(command));
    }
  }
}


const fakeDB = {
  data: {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
  },
  get(key) {
    return this.data[key];
  },
  update(key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
  },
  delete(key) {
    delete this.data[key];
  },
  create(key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
  },
}
// other receivers with same interface
const fakeMongoDB = {}

function client() {
  console.log("DB status", fakeDB.data, "\n");
  commandManager.execute(updateCommand(fakeDB, { key: 'key2', value: 'newValue2' }));
  commandManager.execute(deleteCommand(fakeDB, { key: 'key3' }));
  console.log("DB status", fakeDB.data, "\n");
  commandManager.undo();
  commandManager.undo();
  console.log("DB status", fakeDB.data, "\n");
  commandManager.redo();
  commandManager.redo();
  console.log("DB status", fakeDB.data, "\n");
}

client();
```